# IONIC 2 - GeoLocation ask or permission every time when app open

Tags: ios, permissions, ionic2, geolocation

I am using ionic `Geolocation` Library for getting user current location. 
When i open the application every time it's asking for the permission. I have use the following code to get the current location from user.

```
let options = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true , maximumAge: 0};
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => {

})
```

Can you please help me why it asking for the permission every time.

Thanks

Comment: Because you did not enable location in your phone and `Geolocation` need it to `getCurrentPosition`

Comment: Location service enable and working fine in google map and other applications.

Comment: @mithul: sir how to mange if user is click the deny button of alert,in my case after click deny user current location is not show tell me how to manage such scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen because the Ionic platform may not be fully ready before code requesting a user location gets called. 
[See this Ionic forum discussion.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-plugin-geolocation-location-access-prompt-appears-twice/69357)

The Ionic-Native geolocation plugin, which uses native device location permissions & is only set once, AND the browser window in which the Ionic Cordova app run are BOTH asking for user permission.

In my case, and I presume yours, the alert that shows up on every launch references the browser 'container' and 'index.html', indicating it's the browser asking for permission. The app-specific alert only shows up once on the initial launch after installation.

I had the same problem w/a geolocation service call in a modal that appears right after launch. My solution was to:

1. Inject the `Platform` from ionic-angular into the component
   making the geolocation request, and then
2. Wrap my geolocation call in `platform.ready().then()`, to ensure
   it only ran after the platform was, y'know, "ready."

This removed the duplicate alerts, and it only asks once immediately after first launch.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

 constructor(private platform: Platform, private geo: Geolocation) {}

 ngOnInit() {

    this.setLocation(); 
 }

  setLocation() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
        return this.geo.getCurrentPosition()
                       .then(pos => {//do stuff w/position});
     });
  }
```